# Cut Fill Tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, volume, cut-fill

Looking for the equivalent of the Cut Fill Tool in QGIS. I have multiple DSM rasters from a drone that I would like to do a volume analysis on.

A cut-and-fill operation is a procedure in which the elevation of a landform surface is modified by the removal or addition of surface material. The Cut Fill tool summarizes the areas and volumes of change from a cut-and-fill operation. By taking surfaces of a given location at two different time periods, it identifies regions of surface material removal, surface material addition, and areas where the surface has not changed.

How can I do this in QGIS?

Comment: Maybe if you explained what the Cut Fill tool does...

Comment: A cut-and-fill operation is a procedure in which the elevation of a landform surface is modified by the removal or addition of surface material.

The Cut Fill tool summarizes the areas and volumes of change from a cut-and-fill operation. By taking surfaces of a given location at two different time periods, it identifies regions of surface material removal, surface material addition, and areas where the surface has not changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The raster calculator can give you the difference between the original DSM and the new DSM. DSM_o minus DSM_n = DSM_cut-fill. You can then run saga raster volumes in processing to get the volume below the baseline (cut), volume above the baseline (fill) etc. On my machine this info goes into the log message panel under processing. The grass algorithm r.report should give you your area statistics.