# Elevation and Volume relationship curve in QGIS

Tags: qgis, volume, cut-fill

Is there any tool in QGIS3 or any open source tool which does a Volume against Elevation curve when you provide a polygon?

For clarity [enter link description here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/253878/63384) has a good way to calculate the volume from one elevation but if you need the elevation vs volume curve between two elevations this can be time consuming. For example if you need to know the volume vs elevation between 400m and 700m at 0.1m intervals you will need (700 - 400)/0.1 = 3000 surfaces.

I'm trying to calculate the a reservoir dam capacity where I need to know the total volume at a certain elevation of an irregular surface.

What I'm trying to do is something like this:
[How To Calculate Surface/Cut Volume QGIS - Advanced](https://www.pointsnorthgis.ca/blog/how-to-calculate-surfacecut-volume-qgis-advanced/)

However this process is time consuming especially with RL's small resolutions (0.1 m)

There are some commercial tools available to do this such as Global Mapper:

[Cut and Fill Tool - Global Mapper](https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/knowledgebase/global-mapper-19/Cut_and_Fill.htm)

Comment: Did you see the answer of this question? [Cut Fill Tool in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/253878/63384)

Comment: This is ok if you want one surface - but if you want the stage storage between say an elevation at 400m to 700m at 0.1 increments that is 3000 DEM surfaces you need to create.

Comment: Please update your question with additional information in your comment to attract answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not believe it, but you can use QGIS **Hypsometric curves** tool (in `Processing Toolbox > Raster terrain analysis`) exactly for this purpose.

[image]

Please do not forget to reproject your map to a CRS beforehand which uses the units in which you need to get the area.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - but i'm getting different volumes from global mapper. I'll look into why there differences.

Answer (score 2):

Just came across a Youtube tutorial by Hans van der Kwast.

Basically he used a pyQGIS script to iterate a series of elevations, at each iteration the script uses "Raster Surface Volume" to calculate the storage volume under a defined elevation from the base level.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VOb3_x8lYk&t=602s

In my opinion, if you wish to calculate the stage-storage curve in a Dam using a big raster DEM, it would be better to clip the DEM only to the extent of the Dam. And work with the clipped DEM.